# Syntax Error in google-api-python-client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

While attempting to follow the [Appengine quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide) the following error message appears:

`httplib2/__init__.py", line 352
    print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing [`google-api-python-client`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation), the following is recommended:

`pip install -t lib google-api-python-client`

If this command is used in an enviornment running python 3, the lib installed copy will fail.
Better to explicily state pip2:

`pip2 install -t lib google-api-python-client`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but my solution was to run pip in a virtual environment for the correct Python version, in my case it was 2.7.

```
virtualenv --python=python2.7 .venv27
source .venv27/bin/activate
pip2.7 install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```